# How to add filename suffix inside text using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, replace

I am not sure if it's possible. i want to add filename at the end of text file each line.

assume i have a text file `Sam_NEW.txt` `Tom_New.txt` `Robin_New.txt` etc. inside the text follow line available

`test1.rar
test2.rar
test3.rar`

i want to have output

`copy "C:\test1.rar" "F:\Sam_NEW\"
copy "C:\test2.rar" "F:\Sam_NEW\"
copy "C:\test3.rar" "F:\Sam_NEW\"`

`copy "C:\test1.rar" "F:\Tom_New\"
copy "C:\test2.rar" "F:\Tom_New\"
copy "C:\test3.rar" "F:\Tom_New\"`

`copy "C:\test1.rar" "F:\Robin_New\"
copy "C:\test2.rar" "F:\Robin_New\"
copy "C:\test3.rar" "F:\Robin_New\"`

and save the text files. english is not my first language here is the image what i am trying to do

https://i.stack.imgur.com/42IpE.png

here is replace code so far i have.

```
(Get-Content C:\temp\*.txt) -creplace '^', '"C:\' | Set-Content C:\temp\*.txt

(Get-Content C:\temp\*.txt) -creplace '$', '"F:\HOW TO add here filename \"' | Set-Content C:\temp\*.txt
```

i am stuck in last part. how to add file name for the destination folder?

Comment: So the text file has the rar filenames in it already?

Comment: yes these are available inside the text
`test1.rar
test2.rar
test3.rar`

Comment: Please post some code to prove that you have tried some ideas yourself. You'll have to work with `get-content`, `foreach-loop` and `-replace`. We'll be happy to help when you're stuck at a specific point.

Comment: i have update my question. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want something like this:

```
$item = get-item -path "C:\temp\test.txt"
$lines = get-content -path $item.fullname
$newfileoutput = @()
foreach ($line in $lines){
    $newfileoutput += 'copy "C:\' + $line + '" "F:\' + $item.basename + '\"'
}
$newfileoutput | set-content $item.fullname
```

But I can only encourage you to deepen your knowledge of simple cmdlets like `get-item`, `get-content` and the like. I don't have the impression that you understand the code you're writing. Sometimes, less code (and more pipelining) is making things more complicated. Try and write code that you understand.

Comment: thank you so much. sorry i am not that good powershell. but the two line which i wrote i understand that part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this code will do exactly what you're looking for, but I've tried to write it in a clear way with lots of explanation. Hopefully the techniques and cmdlets in here are helpful to you.

```bsh
$RarFileNames   = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Filter *.rar | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$NewFolderPaths = Get-ChildItem -Path F:\ -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

foreach( $NewFolderPath in $NewFolderPaths )
{
    foreach( $RarFile in $RarFileNames )
    {
        # EXAMPLE: C:\Temp\test1.rar
        $RarFilePath = Join-Path -Path $RarFolderPath -ChildPath $RarFile

        # EXAMPLE: Sam_New.txt
        $NewFileName = (Split-Path $NewFolderPath -Leaf) + '.txt'

        # EXAMPLE: F:\Sam_NEW\Sam_NEW.txt
        $NewFilePath = Join-Path -Path $NewFolderPath -ChildPath ($NewFileName)

        # This is the string that will be saved in the .txt file
        # EXAMPLE: copy "C:\Temp\test1.rar" "C:\Sam_NEW\"
        $StringToOutput = 'copy "' + $RarFilePath + '" "' + $NewFolderPath + '"'

        # Append that string to the file:
        Add-Content -Value $StringToOutput -Path $NewFilePath
    }
}
```